# How can I combine these two stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to combine these two stored procedures so that it returns the values of both under their own headings/columns so the results are as followed "Support Hours Worked" "Support Hours Charged" "Development Hours Worked" and "Development Hours Charged"

Query One

```
USE [Database]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_JobTimeSystem_FetchSupport] ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_JobTimeSystem_FetchSupport]

@FromDate                           datetime,
@ToDate                             datetime,
@SystemUserID                       uniqueidentifier

AS

;WITH cte AS (

SELECT
       DATEPART(Year, StartTime) AS YearNumber,
       DATEPART(Month, StartTime) AS MonthNumber,
       DateName(Month, StartTime) + ' ' + CAST(DatePart(Year, StartTime) AS nvarchar(50)) AS TimePeriod,
       DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, StartTime), 0) AS FromDate,
       DateDiff(minute, StartTime, EndTime) AS JobTime,
       tblJobWorkLog.ChargeableTime

FROM
       tblJobWorkLog
       INNER JOIN tblJob ON tblJobWorkLog.JobID = tblJob.JobID
       INNER JOIN tblContact ON tblJob.ContactID = tblContact.ContactID

WHERE
       tblJobWorkLog.StartTime >= @FromDate
       AND tblJobWorkLog.EndTime <= @ToDate
       AND (WorkLogJobTypeID = 'FA5E6979-D228-44B7-A91B-8DDC8DDC709B' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '3171B295-60E9-4724-95A3-04FA182D7D43' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '52c2691f-ff0a-4263-a440-8a309f868f93')
       AND SystemUserID = @SystemUserID

)

SELECT
       FromDate,
       (SUM(JobTime) / 60.0) HoursWorked,
       SUM(ChargeableTime) AS HoursCharged

FROM
       cte

GROUP BY
       FromDate
ORDER BY
       FromDate
```

Query Two

```
USE [Database]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_JobTimeSystem_FetchDevelopment]    Script Date: 18/05/2015 09:23:53 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_JobTimeSystem_FetchDevelopment]

@FromDate                           datetime,
@ToDate                             datetime,
@SystemUserID                       uniqueidentifier

AS

;WITH cte AS (

SELECT
       DATEPART(Year, StartTime) AS YearNumber,
       DATEPART(Month, StartTime) AS MonthNumber,
       DateName(Month, StartTime) + ' ' + CAST(DatePart(Year, StartTime) AS nvarchar(50)) AS TimePeriod,
       DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, StartTime), 0) AS FromDate,
       DateDiff(minute, StartTime, EndTime) AS JobTime,
       tblJobWorkLog.ChargeableTime

FROM
       tblJobWorkLog
       INNER JOIN tblJob ON tblJobWorkLog.JobID = tblJob.JobID
       INNER JOIN tblContact ON tblJob.ContactID = tblContact.ContactID

WHERE

       tblJobWorkLog.StartTime >= @FromDate
       AND tblJobWorkLog.EndTime <= @ToDate
       AND (WorkLogJobTypeID = 'D0E910B1-B4BD-430C-AD04-EB4E67946806' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'B0BBF362-294D-4262-BED8-EDA7EE74745B' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '1E333ADC-E4F2-4042-8B65-E25F2770D59F'
       OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'A445B7CE-E9E4-48E6-B5AA-83C83F045315' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '1D83F510-87FA-446E-9337-3D0376210D57' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'B59C1596-E1D0-4118-A805-65208E27AFB5' OR
       WorkLogJobTypeID = 'F44A4B3C-B149-45A8-A9F0-5A57883482FD')
       AND SystemUserID = @SystemUserID
)

SELECT
       FromDate,
       (SUM(JobTime) / 60.0) HoursWorked,
       SUM(ChargeableTime) AS HoursCharged

FROM
       cte

GROUP BY
       FromDate
ORDER BY
       FromDate
```

I know there's definitely a way to put these together but I only started SQL a few weeks ago and don't really know how to go about doing it, a few pointers even would mean a lot, thank you.

Comment: if you don't want to duplicate your code and use existing procedures, you can insert the output of the 2 procedures into respective temp tables and then join the tables together  using `FromDate`.

Comment: Are you expecting the results separately or in the same dataset? If so, you only need to merge the two `WHERE` conditions with `OR`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of SQL! Hopefully the below code will help you out.

Basically create a query with the common select between the two queries and use a case statement to filter out further the unique results you want from both the queries:

```
WITH cte AS (

SELECT
       DATEPART(Year, StartTime) AS YearNumber,
       DATEPART(Month, StartTime) AS MonthNumber,
       DateName(Month, StartTime) + ' ' + CAST(DatePart(Year, StartTime) AS nvarchar(50)) AS TimePeriod,
       DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, StartTime), 0) AS FromDate,
       DateDiff(minute, StartTime, EndTime) AS JobTime,
       tblJobWorkLog.ChargeableTime,
       WorkLogJobTypeID

FROM
       tblJobWorkLog
       INNER JOIN tblJob ON tblJobWorkLog.JobID = tblJob.JobID
       INNER JOIN tblContact ON tblJob.ContactID = tblContact.ContactID

WHERE
       tblJobWorkLog.StartTime >= @FromDate
       AND tblJobWorkLog.EndTime <= @ToDate
       AND SystemUserID = @SystemUserID

)

SELECT
       FromDate,
       Case when WorkLogJobTypeID = 'FA5E6979-D228-44B7-A91B-8DDC8DDC709B' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '3171B295-60E9-4724-95A3-04FA182D7D43' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '52c2691f-ff0a-4263-a440-8a309f868f93' then (SUM(JobTime) / 60.0) end as SupportHoursWorked,
       Case when WorkLogJobTypeID = 'FA5E6979-D228-44B7-A91B-8DDC8DDC709B' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '3171B295-60E9-4724-95A3-04FA182D7D43' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '52c2691f-ff0a-4263-a440-8a309f868f93' then SUM(ChargeableTime) end AS SupportHoursCharged,
       Case when WorkLogJobTypeID = 'D0E910B1-B4BD-430C-AD04-EB4E67946806' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'B0BBF362-294D-4262-BED8-EDA7EE74745B' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '1E333ADC-E4F2-4042-8B65-E25F2770D59F' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'A445B7CE-E9E4-48E6-B5AA-83C83F045315' 
       OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '1D83F510-87FA-446E-9337-3D0376210D57' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'B59C1596-E1D0-4118-A805-65208E27AFB5' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'F44A4B3C-B149-45A8-A9F0-5A57883482FD' then (SUM(JobTime) / 60.0) end as DevelopmentHoursWorked,
       Case when WorkLogJobTypeID = 'D0E910B1-B4BD-430C-AD04-EB4E67946806' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'B0BBF362-294D-4262-BED8-EDA7EE74745B' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '1E333ADC-E4F2-4042-8B65-E25F2770D59F' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'A445B7CE-E9E4-48E6-B5AA-83C83F045315' 
       OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '1D83F510-87FA-446E-9337-3D0376210D57' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'B59C1596-E1D0-4118-A805-65208E27AFB5' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'F44A4B3C-B149-45A8-A9F0-5A57883482FD' then SUM(ChargeableTime) end as DevelopmentHoursCharged

FROM
       cte

GROUP BY
       FromDate, WorkLogJobTypeID
ORDER BY
       FromDate
```

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for your reply, it seems to be exactly what i'm looking for but upon testing i get the following error: "Column 'cte.WorkLogJobTypeID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." Help please..

Comment: Hi @James you could try add it to the grouping as I have above. If that doesn't work out for you then you could try putting a max around WorkLogJobTypeID i.e: Max(WorkLogJobTypeID)

Answer (score 0):

You can define 2 CTEs in one query, and then join them up on the UserID like this:

```
USE [Database]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_JobTimeSystem_FetchSupport] ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_JobTimeSystem]

@FromDate                           datetime,
@ToDate                             datetime,
@SystemUserID                       uniqueidentifier

AS

;WITH cte AS (

SELECT
       DATEPART(Year, StartTime) AS YearNumber,
       DATEPART(Month, StartTime) AS MonthNumber,
       DateName(Month, StartTime) + ' ' + CAST(DatePart(Year, StartTime) AS nvarchar(50)) AS TimePeriod,
       DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, StartTime), 0) AS FromDate,
       DateDiff(minute, StartTime, EndTime) AS JobTime,
       tblJobWorkLog.ChargeableTime

FROM
       tblJobWorkLog
       INNER JOIN tblJob ON tblJobWorkLog.JobID = tblJob.JobID
       INNER JOIN tblContact ON tblJob.ContactID = tblContact.ContactID

WHERE
       tblJobWorkLog.StartTime >= @FromDate
       AND tblJobWorkLog.EndTime <= @ToDate
       AND (WorkLogJobTypeID = 'FA5E6979-D228-44B7-A91B-8DDC8DDC709B' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '3171B295-60E9-4724-95A3-04FA182D7D43' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '52c2691f-ff0a-4263-a440-8a309f868f93')
       AND SystemUserID = @SystemUserID

)
, cte2 AS (

SELECT
       DATEPART(Year, StartTime) AS YearNumber,
       DATEPART(Month, StartTime) AS MonthNumber,
       DateName(Month, StartTime) + ' ' + CAST(DatePart(Year, StartTime) AS nvarchar(50)) AS TimePeriod,
       DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, StartTime), 0) AS FromDate,
       DateDiff(minute, StartTime, EndTime) AS JobTime,
       tblJobWorkLog.ChargeableTime

FROM
       tblJobWorkLog
       INNER JOIN tblJob ON tblJobWorkLog.JobID = tblJob.JobID
       INNER JOIN tblContact ON tblJob.ContactID = tblContact.ContactID

WHERE

       tblJobWorkLog.StartTime >= @FromDate
       AND tblJobWorkLog.EndTime <= @ToDate
       AND (WorkLogJobTypeID = 'D0E910B1-B4BD-430C-AD04-EB4E67946806' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'B0BBF362-294D-4262-BED8-EDA7EE74745B' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '1E333ADC-E4F2-4042-8B65-E25F2770D59F'
       OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'A445B7CE-E9E4-48E6-B5AA-83C83F045315' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = '1D83F510-87FA-446E-9337-3D0376210D57' OR WorkLogJobTypeID = 'B59C1596-E1D0-4118-A805-65208E27AFB5' OR
       WorkLogJobTypeID = 'F44A4B3C-B149-45A8-A9F0-5A57883482FD')
       AND SystemUserID = @SystemUserID
)
SELECT
       a.FromDate,
       (SUM(a.JobTime) / 60.0) SupportHoursWorked,
       SUM(a.ChargeableTime) AS SupportHoursCharged,
       (SUM(b.JobTime) / 60.0) DevelopmentHoursWorked,
       SUM(b.ChargeableTime) AS DevelopmentHoursCharged


FROM
       cte as a

JOIN 
      cte2 as b
ON
     a.SystemUserID=b.SystemUserID

GROUP BY
       a.FromDate
ORDER BY
       a.FromDate
```

But obviously without test data, I can only guess that this will work based on what you have shown us here.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the output in a new procedure which uses the existing routines, then you have less maintenance if you need to change the procedures.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.FetchHours
@FromDate datetime,
@ToDate datetime,
@SystemUserID uniqueidentifier
AS
    EXEC [dbo].[usp_JobTimeSystem_FetchSupport] @FromDate, @ToDate, @SystemUserID;
    EXEC [dbo].[usp_JobTimeSystem_FetchDevelopment] @FromDate, @ToDate, @SystemUserID;
GO
```

Comment: That would produce two result sets, he's looking for a solution that merges the two results.

Comment: @JohnnyBell - I see what you are saying but, if I'm being pedantic, the question is not very clear as to the desired output. There's a comment on the question asking "Are you expecting the results separately or in the same dataset?". If that is answered I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your stored procedures return result set you can save the result into temporary table (as @ughai mentioned in comment).

Something like (I am not sure if the syntax is correct):

```
INSERT INTO #temp1 
FROM
EXEC [dbo].[usp_JobTimeSystem_FetchSupport] @FromDate, @ToDate, @SystemUserID;
```

The same for second query:

```
INSERT INTO #temp2
FROM
EXEC [dbo].[usp_JobTimeSystem_FetchDevelopment] @FromDate, @ToDate, 
@SystemUserID;
```

Then you can write a new `SELECT` query which merges results above.
The best would be to close everything in separate stored procedure.

Both temp tables should be created before you use them.

Some pseudocode:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.FetchHours
@FromDate datetime,
@ToDate datetime,
@SystemUserID uniqueidentifier
AS

    CREATE TABLE #temp1...
    CREATE TABLE #temp2...

    INSERT INTO #temp1 
    FROM
    EXEC [dbo].[usp_JobTimeSystem_FetchSupport] @FromDate, @ToDate, @SystemUserID;

    INSERT INTO #temp2
    FROM
    EXEC [dbo].[usp_JobTimeSystem_FetchDevelopment] @FromDate, @ToDate, 
    @SystemUserID;

    SELECT your columns
    FROM #temp1 JOIN #temp2 ON ...
    ORDER BY ...
GO
```

You can use variable table instead of temporary table if size of your data is not too big (over thousands of rows).